# Why is substr($fileinfo->getFilename(),'-3-sml') !== false not working?

Tags: php

My goal is to move the first file containing -3-sml in the filename from temp to b2. What my code does is move every file to b2. Why is that and what to change?

```
$name = "";
$dname = "";
$dir = new DirectoryIterator('temp/');
foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) 
{
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) 
    {
        if (substr($fileinfo->getFilename(),'-3-sml') !== false) 
        {
            rename("temp/".$fileinfo->getFilename(), "b2/".$fileinfo->getFilename());
            $name = $fileinfo->getFilename();
            $dname = "http://domain.com/b2/".$fileinfo->getFilename();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: I tried

```
if (substr($fileinfo->getFilename(),'-3-sml') !== false) 
{
    echo $fileinfo->getFilename()."<br>";
    continue;
    rename("temp/".$fileinfo->getFilename(), "b2/".$fileinfo->getFilename());
    $name = $fileinfo->getFilename();
    $dname = "http://oneitis.mygrabrede.de/b2/".$fileinfo->getFilename();
    break;
}
```

and it seems that `substr($fileinfo->getFilename(),'-3-sml') !== false` doesn't filter anything, so every filename goes through. Why?

EDIT: Solution is: it has to be `strpos` not `substr`.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to move **only the first matching file**, you can use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), and access the **first item** on the `array`, i.e.:

```
$origin_path = "/somepath/temp";
$dest_path = "/somepath/b2";

$files = glob("$origin_path/*-3-sml*");
$fileName = basename($files[0]);
if(!is_dir("$dest_path")){
    mkdir("$dest_path", 0777);
    rename($files[0],"$dest_path/$fileName" );
}else{
    rename($files[0],"$dest_path/$fileName" );
}
```

---

If you need to search inside multiple sub-folders, use this **recursive glob** function:

```
function rglob($pattern='*', $flags = 0, $path='')
{
    $paths=glob($path.'*', GLOB_MARK|GLOB_ONLYDIR|GLOB_NOSORT);
    $files=glob($path.$pattern, $flags);
    foreach ($paths as $path) { $files=array_merge($files,rglob($pattern, $flags, $path)); }
    return $files;
}
```

and change from

```
 $files = glob("$origin_path/*-3-sml*");
```

to

```
 $files = rglob("$origin_path/*-3-sml*");
```

Answer (score 0):

Change substr() to strpos()
Substr for find out substring

Strpos will return position of specific string